# Why does my computers memory rapidly disappear when I try to process rasters?

Tags: r, performance, storage, raster, r-raster

I am working with a set of 13 .tif raster files, 116.7 MB each, containing data on mangrove forest distributions in West Africa. Each file holds the distribution for one year (2000-2012). The rasters load into R without any problems and plot relatively easily as well, taking ~20 seconds using base plot() and ~30 seconds using ggplot().

I am running into problems when I try to do any sort of processing or analysis of the rasters. I am trying to do simple raster math, subtracting the 2000 mangrove distribution raster from the 2000 raster to show deforestation hotspots, but as soon as I do, the memory on my computer starts rapidly disappearing.

I have 48GB of drive space free, but when I start running the raster math, I start to lose a GB of storage every few seconds. This continues until my storage is almost empty, I get a notification from my computer that my storage is critically low, and I have to stop R from running. I am running on a MacBook Pro 121GB storage 8GB ram Big Sur 11.0.1. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Here's my code:

```
#import cropped rasters
crop2000 <- raster("cropped2000.tif")
crop2001 <- raster("cropped2001.tif")
crop2002 <- raster("cropped2002.tif")
crop2003 <- raster("cropped2003.tif")
crop2004 <- raster("cropped2004.tif")
crop2005 <- raster("cropped2005.tif")
crop2006 <- raster("cropped2006.tif")
crop2007 <- raster("cropped2007.tif")
crop2008 <- raster("cropped2008.tif")
crop2009 <- raster("cropped2009.tif")
crop2010 <- raster("cropped2010.tif")
crop2011 <- raster("cropped2011.tif")
crop2012 <- raster("cropped2012.tif")

#look at 2000 distribution
plot(crop2000)

#look at 2012 distribuion
plot(crop2012)

#subtract 2000 from 2012 to look at change
chg00_12 <- crop2012 - crop2000
```

Comment: R is in-memory and RAM is the issue here.  Working with raster files can often generate a lot of intermediate data as calculations are done. Try working with a sequence of subsets of your data, if possible, so R wont need all data to be kept in memory at the same time

Answer (score 0):

If you work with large datasets that cannot be all kept in RAM, raster will save them to temporary files. This can be especially demanding with raster math, as each step will create a new file. e.g with Raster* `x`

```
y <- 3 * (x + 2) - 5
```

would create three temp files. First for `(x+2)`, then for `*3`, and then for `-5`. You can avoid that by using functions like `calc` and `overlay`

```
y <- raster::calc(x, function(i) 3 * (i + 2) - 5)
```

That would only create one temp file. Or none if you provide a filename (which makes it also easier to delete), and perhaps use compression (see ?writeRaster).

Also see ?raster::removeTmpFiles

You can also increase the amount of RAM that raster is allowed to use. See `?raster::rasterOptions`.